# SSH Login to jenkins Users

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ssh

After facing lots of permission issues with system user and Jenkins user, tried to make things as a Jenkins user, it worked, no permission issues was there.
So my question is how to allow Jenkins users to login(ssh) into server using Jenkins username and password, so that they can edit and create files in the server and build in Jenkins without permission issues.

Comment: Have you seen [Securing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins) ff. already?

Comment: Role based strategy and Unix user group..

Answer (score 0):

Add the ssh public key of the users to the `/home/<jenkinsuser>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Then users can login with `ssh -l <jenkinsuser> <servername>`; no password needed.